# French localization in xfce4.12 for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker, xfce, remote-desktop

I'm trying to get an xfce4 (version 4.12) French environment up and running with a "headless" vnc session courtesy of this [docker image](https://github.com/ConSol/docker-headless-vnc-container/blob/master/Dockerfile.ubuntu.xfce.vnc).

If I use the original word for word and just install the French locale via something like

```
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y locales && \
    sed -i -e 's/# fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales
```

Followed by setting the environment variable it is fine and I can get the menus in [French](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXoF7.jpg)

However, if I try exactly the same with a `FROM ubuntu:18.04` I get some part of the UI [not in French](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C50eI.jpg).

I might be missing something obvious as I'm still very new to these environments. In my searching of forums and issues I could not find anything relating to my problem so any help or advice is appreciated.

Pictures of French UI on ubuntu 16 then ubuntu 18 below

[image: French UI]

vs
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Comment line 42 then append the following lines to your `Dockerfile` = `Dockerfile.ubuntu.xfce.vnc`:

```
# ENV LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en' LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt -y install language-pack-fr \
    && apt -y install thunar-data \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y locales \
    && locale-gen fr_FR.UTF-8 \
    && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales \
    && update-locale LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
ENV LANG fr_FR.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL fr_FR.UTF-8
```

then run:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.ubuntu.xfce.vnc .
```

check it (use `docker image ls`):

```
docker run <id latest created image here> locale
```

Start Thunar with: `LANG=fr_FR.utf-8 thunar`

Comment: Thanks for replying, I don't get anything different doing that though. (images here https://imgur.com/a/lyC2ohd ) This is with ubuntu:18.04.

Comment: @Jose You are welcome, try installing `language-pack-fr`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: unfortunately that does not work :(. https://imgur.com/a/XqA2lOh I have tried installing other language packs as well like `language-pack-fr-base` or `language-pack-gnome-fr`. I'm guessing there's some difference between Ubuntu 16 and Ubuntu 18 that is making Thunar not co-operate with me (because if I use Ubuntu 16 it works for a fact). The github project does not look like it is maintained anymore either

Comment: @Jose use `LANG=fr_FR.utf-8 thunar` to start thunar. You can add it to shortcut as command line to start thunar.

Comment: I really thought that would work, but it did not. https://imgur.com/a/LZHCxix

Comment: @Jose I have update my answer adding `thunar-data` it should work for you.

Comment: firstly thanks again for trying so hard to help but unfortunately this is not it either. https://imgur.com/a/KtBdfbS . I'm a tad happy there as it means that I now do not need to go looking for other application specific language extensions for other applications installed. I may need to look more into any notable differences between ubuntu 18 and 16 to check if any changes would break xfce4.12.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but more of a workaround.
I was able to get Thunar into French by taking an `mo` file from an ubuntu 16 version of this application and placing it in `/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES` or `/usr/share/locale-langpack/fr/LC_MESSAGES`

If you want other applications localized, then the way I found was to use the respective applications `po` file and then run `msgfmt fr.po -o applicationname.mo`

So for example we take Thunar

1. Get the PO file from their gitlab project https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/thunar
2. Run `msgfmt fr.po -o Thunar.mo` in your console on the file you get
3. Copy and paste `Thunar.mo` into either `/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES` or `/usr/share/locale-langpack/fr/LC_MESSAGES` (I normally use the first option but on another setup of mine it seems to work)

And hurrah we have Thunar in French on Ubuntu 18 on XFCE
[image]

*Note that when I tried this with something like baobab, I also needed to have `language-pack-gnome-fr` and possibly `language-pack-fr-base` installed so you may need those as well.